# Exercise on Cyclic Group

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

Let $G$ be a finite cyclic group of order $n$. Let $a$ be a generator. Let $r$ be an integer $\neq 0$, and relatively prime to n.

Show that $a^r$ is also a generator of $G$.

**Proof:** $G=\langle a\rangle$ such that $a^n=1$

$|a^r|=\frac{|a|}{\gcd(r,n)}=|a|$

Since $|a^r|=|a|$m then $G=\langle a^r\rangle $.

Is my proof correct ?

Comment: Your question is?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: @fretty If my proof is correct

Comment: Your proof is correct but are you allowed to assume the formula for the order in terms of the gcd? How have you proved this?

Comment: There is a simple proof that doesn't use this formula. Can you find it? Hint: Find a power of $a^r$ that gives $a$, then $\langle a^r\rangle$ contains all powers of $a$, i.e. must equal $G$.

Comment: Your proof relies completely on $$|a^r|=\frac{|a|}{\text{g.c.d.(r,n)}}\;$$ Can you prove this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way:

$$g.c.d(r,n)=1\implies \;\exists\,x,y,\in\Bbb Z\;\;s.t.\;\; xr+yn=1$$

and from here

$$a=a^1=a^{rx+yn}=\left(a^r\right)^x\left(a^n\right)^y=\left(a^r\right)^x\implies \langle a\rangle \subset \langle a^r\rangle$$